# CheckboxList event in MVC3 razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I am creating a checkboxlist for communicationtypes in MVC3 razor my problem is when i am clicked on the checkbox then only it is selecting but i want to click on the text also it is to be selected

My controller code:

```
   IEnumerable<M_TblCommunicationType> communicationlList = (from x in db.M_TblCommunicationType select x).ToList();
   ViewBag.communication = communicationlList.Select(c => new SelectListItem
   {
      Text = c.Communication.ToString(),
      Value = c.Communication_Type.ToString()
   });
```

My view code:

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.Communication_Type)<span class="mandatory">
                * </span></li>
            <li class="input">
                <div class="other">
                    @{IEnumerable<SelectListItem> comminicationType = ViewBag.communication;
                      foreach (var item in comminicationType)
                      { 
                        <input type="checkbox" name="Communication_Typeids" value="@item.Value" id='communicationtype'/>
                        <label for="@item.Value">@item.Text</label>
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Communication_Type)
```

Answer (score 0):

`for` attribute of label should be used with the `id` of the element to bind

Try this :

```
<label for="communicationtype">@item.Text</label>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes it is working but it is working for only one checkbox but i have four checkboxes. whatever the text is i am selected the first checkbox only selecting

Comment: <input type="checkbox" name="Communication_Typeids" value="@item.Text" id="@ViewBag.communication@(item)" />
                      
<label for="@ViewBag.communication@(item)">@item.Text</label>               I tried like this but its not working!!!!

Comment: What do you get in `ViewBag.communication@(item)`. Try `@ViewBag.communication(@item)`

Comment: Does view bag returns only a single value for id ?

Comment: @ViewBag.communication(@item) i tried with this but getting error like  "Cannot invoke a non-delegate type"

Comment: Thats the problem. you need to be distinct. It will assign all the values to all the id's

Comment: Initialize a variable in the `foreach` and try like this `ViewBag.communication(item(i))` before end of loop increment the variable(say i)