# Checkbox skills clickable in mvc3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [CheckboxList event in MVC3 razor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14021204/checkboxlist-event-in-mvc3-razor)

Can any one help me with this?
When I click on the checkbox then only the checkbox is selecting but I want to select the checkbox even if I click on the label as well.

My controller is:

```
 IEnumerable<TblSkill> skillList = (from x in db.TblSkills select x).ToList();
                ViewBag.skill = skillList.Select(c => new SelectListItem{
                    Text = c.Skills.ToString(),
                    Value = c.SkillsId.ToString()
                });
```

and my view is:

```
<div class="editor-field">
            @{
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> skill = ViewBag.skill;
       foreach (var item in skill)
       {           
                <input type="checkbox" name="skillsId" value="@item.Text" /> 
                <label>@item.Text</label>  
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Skills)
       }
            }
           </div>
```

Comment: (as on the other one) - congratulations this is duplicate 2 of 2...

Answer (score 0):

The checkbox has property called "Text" use that property.
Label will be rendered automatically and When you click on that label. Checkbox will be toggled.

Comment: I changed the code like this but not getting the "Text" property is not displaying in "intelisense"                   <input id="@skill@(item)" type="checkbox" name="skillsId" value="@item.Text" /> 
                <label for= "@skill@(item)">@item.Text</label>

Comment: Use Html.CheckBox.   Don't use <input type="checkbox">

Comment: thanx for reply I used like this but not getting                                      @Html.CheckBox("Skills", false, new {value="@item.Text", text = item.Text });                                                           
                <label for= "@ViewBag.skill@(item)">@item.Text</label>

Comment: I used like this but it is selecting only first checkbox Can u help me for this ........                                         @Html.CheckBox("Skills", false , new {value="@item.Text"});                                                             
                <label for= "Skills">@item.Text</label>

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<input id="kibble" type="checkbox" value="kibble" />
<label for="kibble">Kibble</label>
```

`for="kibble"` - where "kibble" is `id`

Demo: [Labels for Checkboxes](http://www.10sharpdesign.com/accessibility/forms/3b-ii-labels-checkboxes.html)

Comment: Can u show with my sample code